# Android Activity is there in android manifest but it is still not found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have tried almost all the questions I have found related to the question that I am posting here.
I am following a tutorial from 
http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/
I have come across this exception that:

[Activity Not Found Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHP5Y.png)

This is manifest file code :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"/>
```

This is the code:

private class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask  {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params) {

        // Obtain feed
        DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
        feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);

        // launch List activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

        // kill this activity
        finish();
    }

}
```

Kindly see to this that why is this exception being raised.

Comment: Use import `com.example.sophiaajaz.rssapp. ListActivity ` instead of `android.app. ListActivity`

Comment: I did this solution but still didnot work @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListActivity` is also an Android class. You can see in your log that its the Android variant that is being launched.
At the top of your file you can probably see `import android.app.ListActivity` while it should have been `import your.package.ListActivity`

Comment: Thank you for the help @0xDEADC0DE . I actually imported android.app.ListActivity !